# Option Prop Changing Default Selected Value - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr, prop

So I have a selection list, and if the default value hasn't been changed from `---` then return to the form false. Pretty much for validation purposes so we know they picked a title. The problem is that for some reason `prop()` is changing the default value to the bottom most value. Is there a way to keep this from happening? Here's a JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/EzPEz/5/)

And here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<form onSubmit="return checkSelect()">
<select id="title" name="title"> <option value="---">---</option> <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option> <option value="Asst. Admin.">Asst. Admin.</option> <option value="Director">Director</option> <option value="Asst. Director">Asst. Director</option> <option value="IT Director">IT Director</option> <option value="Manager">Manager</option> <option value="Medical Officer">Medical Officer</option> <option value="Other">Other</option> </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

​**JS**

```
function checkSelect(){
try{
    var val = $('#title option').attr('selected', 'selected').val();
    alert(val);
    return false;
    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

​**EDIT**

I tried to change to attr() to see if that would help, but it produces the same problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `attr(attribute, value)` function you use is setting the attribute to a value, see [the attr doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2). Try changing:

```
var val = $('#title option').attr('selected', 'selected').val();
```

to:

```
var val = $('#title option:selected').val();
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNK72/).

Comment: That worked, thank you! I must be confused on what prop() does.

Comment: Glad I could help :). By the way, your code sample uses `attr`, not `prop`. They do different (but related) things for you. The [prop documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) has a description of the difference.